# How to add HTML via a secure PHP form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a homepage community for Tutors to come and teach people to make art. In these homepages, they should be able to edit their Bio, CSS, etc. I'm attempting to make a SECURE php form that will edit the contents of several HTML files.

http://scribblehub.com/Tutors/Tutors/Template/Index.html

The tabs on that call the following functions:

```js
function home() {

document.getElementById("foreground").innerHTML = "<iframe src='home.html' seamless></iframe>";

}

function about() {

document.getElementById("foreground").innerHTML = "<iframe src='about.html' seamless></iframe>";

}

function tutorials() {

document.getElementById("foreground").innerHTML = "<iframe src='tutorials.html' seamless></iframe>";

}

function questions() {

document.getElementById("foreground").innerHTML = "<iframe src='questions.html' seamless></iframe>";

}
```

I want my users to be able to edit the HTML's listed above with a form. I can handle the authentication, and making it to where only certain users can edit them. Can somebody show me how to write a PHP script that changes the contents of the  tags in all of the HTMLs in the above Javascript? I am also wanting them to be able to use the same method to edit the contents of "stylesheet.css".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the HTML to change based upon some user configuration?

What you may need to do is store your HTML and CSS in a database and associate it with a given user, then when you load the page you can pull out the appropriate data from the database and insert your HTML and populate a `<style>` tag with the appropriate CSS.

If you are more looking for PHP changing the contents of the tags after the page has loaded then you cannot do that with PHP as it is server-side. You will need to this in Javascript.

Comment: Do you know how I could do this in JS? I would much rather do that, as I have some experience with JS.

Comment: You could have do an AJAX request which loads the remote data (you will probably still want your content stored in a DB) and then use Javascript to inject your loaded content into the DOM